# Incorrect signal processing while using dlib detector

Tags: c++, dlib

I try block some signals in the main thread, and then create a dedicated thread to fetch those signals via sigwait. After that, in the main thread I try to use dlib frontal face detector.  If I comment out face detector use, then my code works fine, but with detector the program terminates by any signal. My source code (dlib 19.19):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <thread>
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   sigset_t set;
   sigemptyset(&set);
   sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
   sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
   sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR2);
   pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

   auto t = std::thread([&set]() {
         for (int sig = -1; sig != SIGINT; ) {
              sigwait(&set, &sig);
              printf("Signal handling thread got signal %d\n", sig);
         }
   });

   //auto d = dlib::get_frontal_face_detector(); 
   t.join();
}
```

Moreover, this code works fine:

```
void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *, void *)
{
    printf("Signal %d\n", sig);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    auto d = dlib::get_frontal_face_detector();
    pause();
}
```

Comment: So the dlib call sets up its own signal handler?

Comment: I don’t think so, because the code in second example with the sigaction structure works fine.

Comment: In part, I solved this problem. The problem in function gesvd of fortran based library lapack (It used by svd3 function in dlib/matrix/matrix_la.h). A quick fix could be rebuild Dlib library without liblapack.